# Web Based OpenID Logins and Mobile Apps Logins

Tags: android, ios, openid

I've built a site that uses DotNetOpenAuth for OAuth / OpenID duties and the site also offers local logins using a cusomised ASP.NET membership implementation.  The site manages user accounts and user profiles with direct access to the security database.

However, all what would normally be in a Data Access Layer is implemented as a WebAPI secured with DotNetOpenAuth.  On top of this we will have mobile apps for android and iOS that will let users use the API with a custom UI developed by any 3rd party that cares to.

What I'm unsure about is how a mobile app could log the user in if the user created an account using an OpenID provider like Facebook for example?

I've noticed that LinkedIn does allow users to log in using their Facebook account (https://www.linkedin.com/reg/join) so how would the LinkedIn mobile app handle this scenario when it only offers a username / password combination at the login screen?

If you click on the LinkedIn Sign Up link on the mobile app it does not offer the sign in with Facebook option.  Only in the browser does it allow the login with Facebook option.

Does anyone have any insight into how all of this hangs together in the background?  How would a user that logged in originally with Facebook use the mobile app to access the same account?

It appears to me that the major players I've looked at so far (FB, LinkedIn) their mobile apps can only work with a native account held on their system.  Facebook only has local accounts so it's a non issue in that case.

I'm pretty confused on this, the glib answer appears to be that mobile apps only work with native accounts where the server your calling is able to authenticate and authorise the user directly, not via a third party as that would need access to browser cookie for information about the service they used to create the account.

Any insights into this would be really appreciated as I cannot see a way to make this work unless the user has a local account.

Thanks,